# Apache stopped working

Tags: server, apache2

I have a forum website which stopped loading and now it's showing the default [page](http://blegends.ru/).

It is strange because all the setting files were automatically generated and there were no problems until latest restart.

Here are the conf files of apache:

```
**all.conf**
<VirtualHost *:80>
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php
ServerAlias *blegends.ru
AssignUserID webserver webserver
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
Alias /playvds-widget /home/webserver/widget
Alias /playvds-donate /home/webserver/donate
Alias /playvds-launcher /home/webserver/launcher
Alias /playvds-phpmyadmin /home/webserver/phpmyadmin
Alias /playvds-net2ftp /home/webserver/net2ftp
</VirtualHost>
<Directory /home/webserver/widget>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /home/webserver/donate>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /home/webserver/launcher>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /home/webserver/phpmyadmin>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /home/webserver/net2ftp>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/html>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And the website related conf file:

```
**blegends.ru.conf**
<VirtualHost *:80>
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php
ServerName blegends.ru
AssignUserID webserver webserver
DocumentRoot /home/webserver/www/blegends.ru
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
Alias /playvds-widget /home/webserver/widget
Alias /playvds-donate /home/webserver/donate
Alias /playvds-launcher /home/webserver/launcher
Alias /playvds-phpmyadmin /home/webserver/phpmyadmin
Alias /playvds-net2ftp /home/webserver/net2ftp
</VirtualHost>
<Directory /home/webserver/www/blegends.ru>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /home/webserver/widget>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /home/webserver/donate>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /home/webserver/launcher>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /home/webserver/phpmyadmin>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /home/webserver/net2ftp>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/html>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

The forum is based in the directory /home/webserver/www/blegends.ru/

Is it apache which is making trouble or something else? I see the conf files and don't see anything wrong.

**EDIT 1:**
I removed the file "all.conf" and its working now. But I don't understand why that file was not allowing to work before and wether my solution is ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have configured it incorrectly. It seems you have multiple entry for blegends.ru with different locations referring in apache conf and website conf as well. More over in the virtual host tag you can give as

```
<VirtualHost blegends.ru:80>
```

like so and set `_default_:80`  for default serving.

Check your site conf is enabled or not. to enable it try cmd

```
sudo a2ensite yoursite.conf
```

Restart your apache service.